# Python "@property"

Tags: python

Всем привет.

Объясните на пальцах, пожалуйста, механизм создания объекта класса, где содержатся вычисляемые свойства.

Пусть есть такой класс, в котором некоторые свойства объекта хранятся в БД или где-то удаленно.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def age(self):
        sql_serv = SqlServ() # получаем объект, содержащий соединение и курсор
        sql_serv.cursor.execute("select age from pers_table where name=?", self.name)
        result = sql_serv.cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            return result[0]
        return None
```

Заметил, что при создании объекта, его `@property` - свойства заполняются, даже если к ним еще не обращались. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в данном случае, запрос с SQL-серверу будет выполняться

1. При создании объекта

   `person = Person()`
2. При каждом обращении к нему

   `if person.age > 18: print person.age #здесь дважды`

Можно ли избежать запроса в пункте 1?

В пункте 2, можно, в принципе, использовать какой-то кэш.

Comment: Свойства не заполняется, а просто при запросе `person.age` каждый раз выполняется метод. Нет, при инициализации объекта `person.age` не запрашивается. Для пункта 2 - да, лучше сделать кэширование.

Comment: Поэтому и рекомендуется в свойства небольшие куски кода помещать, а не что-то тяжелое, т.к. свойства кажутся чем-то простым, легким. Будь age функцией, фиг бы написали `if person.age() > 18: print person.age()`, скорее уж: `age = person.age() if age > 18: print age`

Answer (score 2):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что в данном случае, запрос с SQL-серверу
> будет выполняться

Неа, при создании объекта не будет обращения к `age`

---

Насчет второго. Да, такой код лучше кешировать, чтобы не было лишних запросов в базу данных, т.к. при объявлении свойств через `@property`, по сути, происходит ассоциация к функции, с этим декоратором (т.е. `person.age` (с `@property`) и `person.age()` (без `@property`) приведут к одному и тому же результату – вызову функции).

Поэтому и рекомендуется в свойства небольшие куски кода помещать, а не что-то тяжелое, т.к. свойства кажутся чем-то простым, легким.

Будь `age` функцией, фиг бы написали:

```
if person.age() > 18:
    print person.age()
```

скорее уж:

```
age = person.age()
if age > 18:
    print age
```

---

Поэтому, имеет смысл кэшировать такие результаты. Тут уже на ваше усмотрение, например можно завести внутреннюю переменную.

Например:

```
...
@property
def age(self):
    if self.__age is None:
        sql_serv = SqlServ() # получаем объект, содержащий соединение и курсор
        sql_serv.cursor.execute("select age from pers_table where name=?", self.name)
        result = sql_serv.cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            self.__age = result[0]

    return self.__age
...
```

Comment: @insolor, не увидел в коде место, которое может вызвать ошибку... Я имел ввиду, что свойства дают иллюзию их легковестности, а они могут через геттеры работать и для свойств, что значения генерируют/запрашивают откуда-то лучше предусмотреть кеширование

Comment: Хотел бы я посмотреть как вы к полю объекта добавите декоратор `@property` :)

Comment: @insolor, наверное, мы друг друга неправильно поняли, добавлю уточнение к первым предложениям ;)