# Что значит символ @ в python?

Tags: python

Видел в разных прогах используется символ @ а потом какое то слово слитно
. Что это могло означать?

Comment: Это могло означать использование [декоратора](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: ещё `__matmul__` (матричное умножение)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/6392739/4496422

Answer (score 4):

Переведу ответ с *enSO* на который указали в комментариях, раз уж подняли вопрос с 18 года.
[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392768/10562663) плюс добавил ссылки на русском. К сожалению их не так много как хотелось бы.

Символ `@` в начале строки используется для декораторов классов, функций и методов.

**Документация для детального ознакомления:**

[PEP 318 Decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) (англ.)

[Python decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) (англ.)

**Объяснения и примеры:**

[Статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/141411/) (рус., 2012 года)

[Python world](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/dekoratory.html) (рус.)

**Наиболее распространенные декораторы, с которыми вы столкнетесь:**

[@property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) (англ.), а [здесь ответ на *ruSO*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704800/python-property) с примером
использования

[@classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) (англ.)

[@staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) (англ.), [ответ на *ruSO*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/865184/209304)

Оффтопик, но об этом заходила речь в комментариях, и так же содержится данная информация в оригинальном ответе.

Если знак `@` находится в середине строки, то это может означать произведение матриц. Доступные методы - [**matmul**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__matmul__), [**rmatmul**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmatmul__), [**imatmul**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__imatmul__)

**Документация**:

[PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) (англ.)

**UPD (26.05.2021)**

Полезно так же будет добавить описание с [Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python#%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B) (приведен пример для декоратора функции):

Декораторы функций — вызываемые объекты, которые принимают другую функцию в качестве аргумента. Декораторы функций могут производить операции с функцией и возвращают либо саму функцию, либо другую заменяющую её функцию или вызываемый объект. То есть, если в коде ранее был прописан декоратор, названный `decorate`, то следующий код:

```py
@decorate
def target():
    print('running target()')
```

эквивалентен этому

```py
def target():
    print(running target())
    target = decorate(target)
```

Пример использования декоратора функции:

```py
>>> def deco(func):
...     def inner():
...         print('running inner()')
...     return inner
…
>>> @deco
... def target():
...     print('running target()')
>>> target()
running inner()
>>> target
<function deco.<locals>.inner at 0.10063b598>
```