# Зачем в питоне нужен @staticmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, static

Есть класс `printer`. У него есть 2 метода, делающие одно и то же. Различие в том, что один из методов - с декоратором `@staticmethod`, а другой - без. Но я могу вызывать оба метода без создания экземпляра класса.

```
class printer():
    ''' Тест @staticmethod '''

    def not_static_print(self, text = 'Example Text'):
        print(text)

    @staticmethod
    def static_print(text = 'Example Text'):
        print(text)
# Не создаю никаких экземпляров
printer.not_static_print(None, 'Emm?')
printer.static_print('Something like this.')
```

Просто для `not_static_print()` я указываю экземпляр, а точнее его отсутствие (`None`)

Есть ли принципиальная разница в использовании этих методов?

Comment: `p = printer()` `p.not_static_print(None, 'Emm?')` а теперь попробуйте вызвать тот `not_static_print` с None первым аргументом :)

Comment: кст, в вашем примере у класса нет полей объекта и в `not_static_print` вы к ним не обращайтесь, а это будет возможно только через `self`, но если вы это сделайте и передадите `None`, то будет ошибка `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute`. Вот для таких случаев и существуют статичные методы -- они не могут работать с полями и методами объекта, но при этом их не сделали просто функциями, т.к. они логически относятся к данному классу / типу

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [В чем отличие статического метода(@staticmethod) и метода класса (@classmethod). Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779684/В-чем-отличие-статического-методаstaticmethod-и-метода-класса-classmethod)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@staticmethod` используется в том случае, когда ваш метод не имеет никакого доступа к тому, что представляет собой класс или объект класса. Он не принимает никаких обязательных аргументов, по типу объекта класса или самого класса.

В первом Вашем методе передается параметр `self`, который может быть использован далее в коде(хоть вы его и не используете), в варианте с `@staticmethod` обратиться к классу либо же объекту не выйдет никак. Вызывается он так же, как и обычный метод.

Более подробно можно почитать тут: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/staticmethod